# External configuration files with Maven

Tags: maven-2, deployment, configuration

What is the Maven approach to deal with config files that will be eventually located outside the generated .war/.ear?

I have some config files that during development are in a common-configuration module which is a dependency of my webapp module, but I want some files to be located at different locations during deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the maven-assembly-plugin:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>src/main/assembly/description.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

the file description.xml should look something like this:

```
<assembly>
    <id></id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
        <format>tar</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>../YourProject/${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/binaries</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>YourProject-${version}.war</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/release/docs</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/docs</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

During deployment you can untar or unzip the generated file. The content of the tar/zip-file will look something like this:

> /binaries/YourProject-1.0.war
>   /docs/readme.txt
>   /docs/documentation.doc

Comment: @user498095: please learn to format your posts properly: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Just realized how the formatting works and where to find help. Thanks for your comment.